# Weird bash-script behavior - generated command works when copy-pasted, but not from script

Tags: bash, ansible

I have written a short bash-script to wrap an ansible playbook command for safety reasons. It's nothing much complicated, and most of the script is irrelevant here. At the end, I put together the ansible command from the variables that were generated from the arguments for the script, like so:

```
ansible-playbook -k $user -i hosts-staging $limit $tags $additionalargs site.yml
```

The generated command works for the most part, except that $additionalargs doesn't seem to have any effect. So I do an echo and look at what the script actually generated:

```
echo ansible-playbook -k $user -i hosts-staging $limit $tags $additionalargs site.yml

output: ansible-playbook -k -u pi -i hosts-staging -l tcameras --tags fulllaunch --extra-vars "agraphite_force_restart=true" site.yml
```

This looks exactly as intended, but the --extra-vars parameter seems to not get passed.
So I copied the line produced by the echo, pasted it in the console and hit enter, and this worked fully, including the --extra-vars argument.

So the script generates what I intend, and if I manually supply the command generated by the script it works... but it doesn't work when the script itself executes the command, or at least not completely.

Can anybody give me a hint as to what might go wrong? below is the full script for reference, although since the output is as expected I don't expect the problem to be located here, but rather that there's some bash pecularity I just don't know about.

```
#!/bin/bash

# brief         Makes graphite deployment via Ansible saver by wrapping it into a script that only needs the most common variables, does not apply to the whole inventory by default, and uses the current staging inventory.
# args (3)      Expects 3 arguments: what to do, who to do it with, and if it should do it with all of them or just with one individual instance
# arg $1        What to do. Valid values are "deploy", "launch" or "restart".
# arg $2        Who to do it with. Valid values are "cameras", "servers" or "all".
# arg $3        Optional: Pass an IP from the inventory to apply the action to.     

# error codes:
# 1: Unexpected number of arguments
# 2: Invalid first argument
# 3: Invalid second argument
# 4: Invalid third argument (optional)
# 5: Optional third argument not compatible with second argument

additionalargs=""

if [ $# -lt 2 ]; then
    echo "Unexpected number of arguments (2 expected). Please pass what (\"deploy\", \"launch\" or \"restart\") and who (\"cameras\", \"servers\" or \"all\")"
    exit 1
fi

if [ $1 == "launch" ]; then
    tags="--tags fulllaunch"
elif [ $1 == "restart" ]; then
    tags="--tags fulllaunch"
    additionalargs='--extra-vars "agraphite_force_restart=true"'
elif [ $1 != "deploy" ]; then
    echo "Invalid argument: "$1"! Must be either \"launch\", \"deploy\" or \"restart\"!"
    exit 2
else
    tags=""
fi

if [ $2 == "cameras" ]; then
    limit="-l tcameras"
    user="-u pi"
elif [ $2 == "servers" ]; then
    limit="-l tservers"
    user="-u ubuntu"
elif [ $2 == "all" ]; then
    limit=""
    user="both"
else 
    echo "Invalid argument: "$2"! Must be either \"cameras\", \"servers\", <ip> or \"all\"!"
    exit 3
fi

if [ $# -eq 3 ]; then
    if [[ $3 == *.*.*.* ]]; then              #quite a superficial check for the validity of an ip address, but it serves to prevent dangerous input
        limit="-l "$3
    else
        echo "Error: optional third parameter must be a valid ip-address!"
        exit 4
    fi
    if [ $user == "both" ]; then
        echo "Error: specific ip cannot be used with parameter \"all\"."
        exit 5   
    fi
fi    


if [[ $user == "both" ]]; then
    #do actions for both cameras and servers
    ansible-playbook -k -u ubuntu -i hosts-staging -l tcameras $tags $additionalargs site.yml 
    ansible-playbook -k -u pi -i hosts-staging -l tservers $tags $additionalargs site.yml 
else
    echo ansible-playbook -k $user -i hosts-staging $limit $tags $additionalargs site.yml
    ansible-playbook -k $user -i hosts-staging $limit $tags $additionalargs site.yml  
fi
```

Comment: This is BashFAQ #50: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: ...there are also a bunch of other bugs here. `==` isn't actually a valid operator in POSIX test -- the only string comparison operator guaranteed by the standard is `=`. And in `[ $user == "both" ]`, you're quoting the thing that doesn't need to be quoted (the literal), but expanding unquoted the thing that *does* need to be quoted (the expansion) -- this would cause a syntax error if you had a name with spaces (they're legal on some platforms; on Windows/Cygwin, they're outright common). Consider running your code through http://shellcheck.net/.

Comment: Thanks. For someone that isn't bashing very regularly, it's really weird to suddenly put the variable in quotes but not the string. I get the why, but it still feels like the completely wrong thing to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this one while writing another script involving rather complex curl commands.
First I found out that you can use

```
set -x
```

In the script to make it show the expanded commands, and I was rather horrified at the mess the quote expansion produced. It expanded nicely in an echo, but passing the whole thing as arguments built a mystic labyrinth of quotes. I also experimented around with quoting the variables, but Ansible doesn't like that too much.

I found that for long commands with many arguments that themselves may contain quotes, it is best to write the whole command in a string within double quotes and escape any quotes inside the arguments, and then pass the whole thing to eval.

In this particular case, the command that actually works looks like this:

```
eval "ansible-playbook -k $user -i hosts-staging $limit $tags $additionalargs site.yml"
```

Comment: Using `eval` that way is very, very bad form -- if any of your variables contains, say, `$(rm -rf $HOME)`, that code would be expanded rather than passed through literally.

Comment: ...the Right Way to collect lists of arguments is in a data structure built for the purpose -- which is to say, an array.

Comment: You mean, like # ansible-playbook ${arguments[@]} ?

Comment: Still missing quotes there. `ansible-playbook "${arguments[@]}"`, if you'd collected your arguments in an array called arguments. (Hopefully you'd also be careful when appending them to that array; ie. `arguments+=( -k "$user" )`, with the quotes).

Comment: but... if I put the array in quotes, isn't then the whole array passed as a single argument...?

Comment: No. Quotes mean "suppress string-splitting and glob expansion". Those are the behaviors that can cause a single string to be expanded to multiple arguments (or, if `nullglob` is set or that string contains only characters in IFS, to a completely empty list of arguments) -- or cause an array to be re-combined with different divisions between arguments than was originally intended.

Comment: Thus, `${foo[@]}` unquoted behaves precisely the same as `${foo[*]}` unquoted under normal conditions (an explicitly empty IFS might change that a bit): Both combine each element with whitespace between them, and then split the elements on whitespace and expand each component created by that splitting process as a glob expression.